# How to translate theme content using site language?

Tags: localization

I have theme. For example code for comments:

```
<?php
'fields'   =>  array(

'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . esc_html__( 'Name','text_domain' ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' placeholder="'.esc_html__( 'Name','text_domain' ) .'"/></p>',

)
    ...
);
?>
```

I have changed site language in admin panel, but i still get 'Name' (english). How to translate theme content using site language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to load the translations using the **load_theme_textdomain** function, and supposed your translations is located in the **library/translations** folder, then you can add the code below in you **functions.php** file.

```
// let's get this party started
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'translations');
function translations() {
  // let's get language support going, if you need it
  load_theme_textdomain( 'text_domain', get_template_directory() . '/library/translations' );
}
```